# String or Binary Data Would Be Truncated: NVARCHAR(MAX), SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I've got a column called `description` of type `NVARCHAR(MAX)` - biggest you can have. I need to return this field with quotes around it, so I'm trying to

```
SELECT QUOTENAME(description, '"')
```

This doesn't work - I get a "string or binary data would be truncated error."

My googling tells me that this problem can be solved by using SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF, but if I do that, I still get the same error anyway.

Normally I would just pull the values into a temp table and use a field that is two characters bigger than the field I'm pulling in, thus ensuring that the `QUOTENAME` function won't cause any problems. How do I make a column two characters bigger than MAX, though?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`QUOTENAME` is a function intended for working with strings containing SQL Server identifier names and thus only works for strings less than or equal to the length of `sysname` ([128 characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql)).

Why doesn't `SELECT '"' + description +'"'` work for you?